# Alterar o hover da classe btn do bootstrap

Tags: css

Olá.

Tenho um menu com bootstrap, porém um determinado item está com a classe btn-success. O problema é quando passo o mouse em cima desse item, o fundo fica branco. Como eu faria para que o fundo permanecesse verde?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       ....
                       <li class="btn-success btn-xs">Acessar</li>
                       ....
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elabore um [mcve], por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar o atributo `!important`?

```
li.btn-success:hover{
   background-color: green !important;
}
```

Com o atributo em questão, será priorizado o `background-color` definido por você.

Comment: Olá Leandro. Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: @Fox.11 Editei a resposta, tente novamente.

Comment: Ao meu ver, utilizar `!important` nunca é solução e nunca deveria ser. O problema pode ser resolvido de maneiras mais apropriadas do que simplesmente forçar o navegador a fazer algo. Mas estas maneiras só serão possíveis de apresentar quando o @Fox.11 apresentar todos os detalhes do problema.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro. Funcionou.

Comment: Olá Anderson. A solução do Leandro funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Nem sempre solução que funciona é uma solução válida.